# strange behavior of str_getcsv

Tags: php, string, csv

I've got a csv file, with content in form of:

```
INN code;Tekst;User id;Project_id;priority;Date
6658172497;мини тестик, выполни ,и закрой задание;255;1;4;2012-12-22    
6658228284;мини тестик, выполни и закрой задание;255;1;4;2012-12-22    
7806351504;мини тестик, выполни и закрой задание;255;1;4;2012-12-22    
7710077498;мини тестик, выполни ,и закрой задание;255;1;4;2012-12-22
```

On my local windows machine (php ver 5.4.7), `str_getcsv($row, ';')` works like it should and splits the rows correctly. But when I try the same on our test machine running CentOS (php ver 5.3.3), part of the second column (`мини тестик`) is cut off, leaving only (`,выполни ,и закрой задание`).
If you place a latin character in front of the column data, it cuts off only the part before the character.

Can't find any help explaining this strange behavior on different OS

Comment: Where does `$row` come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The CSV functions are sensitive to the set locale.
[Set your locale](http://php.net/set_locale) to match the encoding of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried [`setlocale()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setlocale.php)?

Also, I think it might be caused by spaces and commas in your text. Try enclosing the Russian parts in double-quotes, or try [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php#109948).

Hope it works for you.